# Clone Gephi Toolkit from git to eclipse using EGit

Tags: eclipse, git, egit, gephi

I want to clone the [Gephi ToolKit](https://github.com/gephi/gephi-toolkit) to Eclipse using EGit. I follow the exact same steps as with other projects that I cloned successfully. [Import --> Projects From Git --> Clone URI and I c/p the clone url]. Unfortunately I get 75 errors, some of them are:

> ArtifactDescriptorException: Failed to read artifact descriptor for
>   org.gephi:dynamic-impl:jar:0.9-SNAPSHOT: UnresolvableModelException:
>   Failure to find org.gephi:gephi-parent:pom:0.9-SNAPSHOT in
>   http://bits.netbeans.org/maven2/ was cached in the local repository,
>   resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of
>   netbeans has elapsed or updates are forced
>
> ArtifactDescriptorException: Failed to read artifact descriptor for
>   org.gephi:ranking-api:jar:0.9-SNAPSHOT: UnresolvableModelException:
>   Failure to find org.gephi:gephi-parent:pom:0.9-SNAPSHOT in
>   http://bits.netbeans.org/maven2/ was cached in the local repository,
>   resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of
>   netbeans has elapsed or updates are forced
>
> Missing artifact
>   org.netbeans.api:org-netbeans-modules-keyring:jar:RELEASE721
>
> Missing artifact
>   org.netbeans.modules:org-netbeans-modules-masterfs:jar:RELEASE721

Also the src folder seems to be missing.

Answer (score 1):

I faced similar problem.

Gephi uses some artifacts from the Netbeans repository page, which looks unavailable: http://bits.netbeans.org/maven2/ (checked 2015-05-11) :(

I solved the problem by manually copying maven dependencies cache from `~/.m2/org/netbeans/...` and `~/.m2/org/gephi/...` from a machine where everything was set up before.

Answer (score 0):

Check this step by step tutorial (from 2012, might not be fresh):
http://wiki.gephi.org/index.php/Running_from_Eclipse